# What anatomy would a human-like character need in order to produce in its body and spit/spray from the mouth a variety of liquids?

Tags: science-based, biology, anatomy

I want a character to be able to spit/spray from the mouth many different liquids created within the body.

Liquids would include a strong acid, flammable liquid, strong poison/nerve agent, a sticky glue like substance, and I am sure there will be more added at a later date. There may be different versions of each type.

The liquids would be spat/sprayed one at a time or combined if suitable. For example, the acid and the glue combined would create an attack like spitting spiders, but at other times having acid in the glue would not be helpful, so the character would need to be in control of bringing up which ever liquid they need.

I thought they would have individual glands for creating each specific liquid that can be easily released into the throat through some inner muscle control.

The problem with individual glands is it limits the number of chemical liquids the character can make and also maybe the volume able to be sprayed. I had thought either an over-active saliva gland or stomach acid could both dilute to control the chemicals strength and to add volume, but a single liquid for those purposes may not react well with all chemicals.

The ideal option would be a stomach that can create almost any chemical, but I cant think of a science-based mechanism for any chemical to be created instantly, and I don't want the character to be that powerful.

So my question is: other than a multiple glands system, is there a better way to achieve creating and spitting/spraying a variety of liquids?

Comment: Is this a biological entity? Can it be a construct of some sort?

Comment: Never cuddled a toddler, I assume...

Comment: @Willk, sorry yes it is human other than this strange ability

Comment: @Willk by construct do you mean something not biological within in them? that is an option I could explore.

Comment: What about a gland that produce different liquids depending on what you eat, or maybe people from different locations have differents glands, you can use some characters than are able to produce more than one kind of liquid. A race war, accid against flammable would be something interesting.

Comment: @ErickSilva for the moment it is a single character, their personality is pretty sadistic to suit wanting to acid burn, poison or set fire to someone, having a gland with multiple purposes would help, but like a previous answer they might have to carry different food to use at the time, but I like where your going.

Answer (score 2):

Do the chemicals have to be made from substances already in the body?

Here's an idea: the creature has a chemical-mixing pouch in their throat,  and when they want to they can ingest certain chemicals to mix together in the pouch. This means they have to carry around ingredients,  but it will provide a very quick method of brewing whatever substance they want. Simply toss some chemicals in their mouth and spit out the results.

Comment: Sounds like a former flatmate of mine...

Comment: @Tesserae that's an idea, I preferred them not to need to have to carry anything with them but it is something I will give more thought on, thanks

Comment: They either have to carry around the finished chemicals or the ingredients for those chemicals. Making liquids “ex nihilo“ is definitely not science-based.

Answer (score 2):

it could just be one spit at a time things, and not a squirt. maybe they have big cheek pouches containing multiple glands, and they have muscles that they specifically move to activate a gland, and then spit it out once it gets in their mouth. the tongue already blocks certain liquids from getting into the stomach naturally, so all we need is a way to spit it out. maybe whatever makes humans good at spitting could work? or maybe they could have a cat tongue that helps them latch onto liquid so they can open their mouth and fling the spit at someone. that would be my way of dealing with it. oh and the mouth would also have to be resistant to acids and glue's and things like that.

so essentially: big squirrel cheeks with glands in them specifically designed to make a liquid and a tongue that can catch liquid similar to a cat's tongue, and fling it at people.